# How to lock fps of a game in the android virtual device in the Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device

I want to limit the fps of a game. I’ve set the RAM to 128MB and CPU core number to 1, but I still can’t get what I want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.